# Show that if $x_0\in X$ is such that $|f(x_0)|\leq c$ for all $f\in X^*$ with $\|f\|=1$ then $\|x_0\|\leq c$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Proposition: If $X$ is a normed vector space and $x\in X$, then $$\|x\|=\sup\{|f(x)|:f\in X^* ,\|f\|\leq 1\},$$ where $X^*$ is the dual space of $X$.

Problem: Show that if $x_0\in X$ is such that $|f(x_0)|\leq c$ for all $f\in X^*$ with $\|f\|=1$ then $\|x_0\|\leq c$.

I have proved the above proposition and I'm trying to use it to solve the problem. In the problem the linear functionals $f$ have operator norm 1 but it has ignored all those with operator norm less than 1. My guess is $$\sup\{|f(x)|:f\in X^* ,\|f\|\leq 1\}=\sup\{|f(x)|:f\in X^*,\|f\|=1\}.$$ This is just wishful thinking based on the different characterizations of the norm of a linear operator on $X$. But is my guess correct? And could you please give me a hint if it is correct so that I can prove it? Thanks.

Comment: It would be nice if you can add the source/reference  of the problem or the book where it is introduced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a **Corollary** to **Hahn Banach Extension theorem**,see that

Let $X$ be a normed linear space , $a \neq 0 \in X$,then there exists $f \in X'$ such that $||f||  =1$ and $f(a) = ||a||$.

In your case $f(x_{0}) = ||x_{0}||$ and as $||f(x_{0})|| \leq c$ so $||x_{0}|| \leq c$.

Comment: I should have looked at the problem from this angle. Thanks.

Comment: @Janitha357You are welcome!actually it would be good of you could give the reference to  the problem,i would like to know the source of the problem as i too encountered a similar problem but was unable to find the source of the problem.

Comment: It is in my functional analysis lecture notes given as an exercise.

Comment: So my search continues then! ☺

Comment: @Janitha357 and BAYMAX: I will add a link to a conversation about this problem in [functional analysis chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19167/conversation/discuaaion-on-a-problem-usage-of-hbet-and-nice-tricks).

Answer (score 1):

It is the case that $\sup\{|f(x)|:f\in X^* ,\|f\|\leq 1\}=\sup\{|f(x)|:f\in X^*,\|f\|=1\}$. To see this note that if $0<\|f\| < 1$ then $\frac{f(x)}{\|f\|} > f(x)$ and $\big \| \frac{f}{\|f\|} \big \| = 1$.

Then as you note your problem can be solved by the proposition that you already proved.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much.